# Ping server/domain and capture its IP on Linux

Tags: bash, ip, ping

With Windows, you could ping a given domain name and capture the IP as a variable, even if no reply was received. I believe the command looked something like this:

```
ping domain.com
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping /n 1 /w 1 domain.com ^| find "Pinging"') do set ipaddress=%%B"`
```

This is basically what I am trying to do, but within a bash script rather than a batch file. I've stumbled across a lot of questions that are really close, but not quite what I am looking for. I can't seem to figure out the best way to go about this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work, from the command line or in a script:

```
ip=$(ping -c 1 www.google.com | gawk -F'[()]' '/PING/{print $2}')
echo $ip
173.194.34.19
```

EXPLANATION

First the output of the `ping` command being parsed:

```
$ ping -c 1 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.40.209) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par10s12-in-f17.1e100.net (173.194.40.209): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=49.8 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.874/49.874/49.874/0.000 ms
```

- `ip=$(COMMAND)` : assign the output of `COMMAND` to the variable `$ip`.
- `ping -c 1 www.google.com` : ping google, once.
- `gawk` is a powerful scripting language that processes input line by line and fields by field.
- `-F'[()]'` : `-F` sets `gawk`'s field delimiter(s). Here, we are setting it to to a character class (`[ ]`), specifically to open and close parentheses. This means that everything until the first `)` or `(` will be the first field which in `gawk` is `$1`. We are only interested in the first line so we tell `gawk` to print the 2nd field (`$2`), which is the IP, *only* if the current line contains "PING" (`/PING/`).

So, the results of the whole shebang are saved as `ip` which you can then refer to as `$ip`.

Comment: Beautiful! just what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @Jim you can replace `gawk` with `awk` to make it slightly more portable. `gawk` might not be installed on some UNIXs but `awk` should always be there.

Comment: It works like a charm! the other method I was trying with nslookup captured all ips as a single variable. It worked, but I only needed the first one.  
         
 Thank you again for your help! now I can actually move on with my script! XD

Comment: This is so elegant -- I'm using this to get the IP address from `docker.for.mac.localhost` so I can use scality/s3server with boto3 and prevent my mock s3 from thinking `docker.for.mac` is my bucket name.